# How to convert varchar data to time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which had a date column of `date` type, and `timein` and `timeout` columns of type `varchar(max)`.

I'm trying to calculate the total hours between `timein` and `timeout`, but I can't because I can't figure out how to convert the `varchar` to a `time` format.

So far I've tried `CAST(x, AS time)`, `CONVERT(time, x, 114)` (also 108) and I keep getting errors

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Any help you can give is appreciated in advance.

My table's date looks like this:

| EmpID | Date | TimeIn | TimeOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2021-12-13 | 05:55 | 14:30 |

Expected result:

| EmpID | Date | TimeIn | TimeOut | Total_hrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2021-12-13 | 05:55 | 14:30 | 8:35 |

Comment: Clearly *some* of your rows are not converting properly. What does the following return `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE TRY_CAST(TimeIn AS time) IS NULL OR TRY_CAST(TimeOut AS time) IS NULL` Bear in mind that the fact you have a `WHERE` filtering on some rows doesn't mean that the cast will be done after the filtering, it may be done before

Comment: `select convert(time,'14:30',114) t1, convert(time,'05:55',108) t2` runs ok for me

Comment: @charlieface Thank you very much.. i was under the assumption that these columns only contained time,  There was one record with a text value in it which thru the error.  extreme rookie mistake.

Comment: @Veebster - if your columns were defined correctly, this wouldn't be a problem.  Instead of defining them as varchar(max) they should be defined as time with an appropriate precision.  If that isn't possible (for some really bad reason) - then at least force an appropriate formatted string and length using a check constraint and a char(5) data type.  That would avoid some bad data - not all mind you - but most.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors from converting bad time strings, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.
They'll just return NULL when they can't convert/cast it.

**For example**

> ```
> create table yourtable (
>  EmpID int, 
>  [Date] date, 
>  TimeIn varchar(5),
>  TimeOut varchar(5)
> );
>
> insert into yourtable (EmpID, [Date], TimeIn, TimeOut) values
> (123456, '2021-12-14', '05:55', '14:30'),
> (234567, '2020-12-13', 'not.a', 'time!');
>
>
> select *
> , [Total_hrs] = convert(char(5),dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, try_cast(TimeIn as time), try_cast(TimeOut as time)), 0), 108)
> from yourtable
> ```

| EmpID | Date | TimeIn | TimeOut | Total_hrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2021-12-14 | 05:55 | 14:30 | 08:35 |
| 234567 | 2020-12-13 | not.a | time! | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40e254ae138394190bde52c753a9bce8)*

Answer (score 0):

This could give your response in the way you want. I just create my data to test my method and you can get rid of them by replacing your table name in query:

```
with t(EmpID, Date, TimeIn, TimeOut) as(

     select 123456 as EmpID, cast('2021-12-13' as date) as Date, '05:55' as TimeIn, '14:30' as TimeOut      
)
select rt.*, cast(minn/60 as varchar(10)) + ':' + cast(minn%60 as varchar(10)) as Total_hrs
from (
    select c.*, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, convert(time,TimeIn,108), convert(time,TimeOut,114)) minn from t c
)rt
```